MLPclassifier on text and categorical features don't learn, is there a normalisation step missing?
I trained MLPclassifier with 'lbfgs' solver model for document multilabel classification. The data are separated on train and test with 'iterative_train_test_split' from 'skmultilearn.model_selection'. When only the text is used as a feature, the result is good: Accuracy 0,68 and F-1 score 0,79. Then I added two categorical features: company name and supplier name. These are "dirty" features, i.e. the name of the same company can be written differently: with orthographical errors, the full name or only a part of it. I use MinHashEncoder() from scrub library to create vectors for these two features. My pipeline:
{'preprocessor': ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('text', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=<function sentence_tokenize >), 'texte'), ('cat', MinHashEncoder(), ['supplier_norm', 'companyName_norm'])]), 'deepclf': MLPClassifier(early_stopping=True, learning_rate='adaptive', random_state=0, verbose=True)}
The parameter grid is the following:
parameter_grid = { 'preprocessor__text__max_df': [0.8, 0.9], 'preprocessor__text__min_df': [2, 3], 'deepclf__solver': ['adam', 'sgd'], 'deepclf__alpha': [0.1, 0.001, 0.2], "preprocessor__cat__n_components": [5, 10, 30] }
MLPclassifier with 'lbfgs' solver results in error "abnormal termination in LNSRCH".
The other two solvers have 0.0 accuracy in iterations. During the iterations the loss is enormous (ex. '171591797243863955364586957202610192384.00000000'). The iterations finish with the following message: 'Learning rate too small. Stopping.' The best f1-score is abnormally high: 0,96 (while Accuracy is ~0,25 at the same point). The results of predictions: weighted average f1-score: 0.24, Accuracy: 0,27. I suppose that the problem comes from the two categorical features. Is an additional transfromation/normalisation is necessary? What transformations?
